# MNIST Python numpy eigen vectors visualization error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pca, eigenvector

I am trying to perform PCA on [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset, as part of the process I need to generate the eigen vectors and visualize the top features. Following is my algorithm:

1. Load images
2. Subtract mean
3. Generate Covariance matrix
4. Derive eigen vectors and eigen values

It's fairly a simple algorithm to run; my first task is to visualize the top 10 eigen vectors as images. Following is the code that I have so far:

```
__author__      =   "Ajay Krishna Teja Kavuri"


import numpy as np 
import random
from mnist import MNIST
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

class PCAMNIST:


    #Initialization
    def __init__(self):
        #Load MNIST datset
        mnistData = MNIST('./mnistData')
        self.imgTrain,self.lblTrain=mnistData.load_training()
        self.imgTrainSmpl=self.imgTrain[:60000]
        np.seterr(all='warn')


    #1. Subtract the mean because the PCA will work better
    def subMean(self):
        try:
            self.sumImg = np.empty([784,])
            #calculate the sum
            for img in self.imgTrainSmpl:
                imgArr = np.asarray(img)
                self.sumImg = np.add(imgArr,self.sumImg)

            #Calculate the mean array
            self.meanImg = self.sumImg/(len(self.imgTrainSmpl))
            self.meanImg = np.nan_to_num(self.meanImg)

            #subtract it out
            index=0
            for img in self.imgTrainSmpl:
                imgArr = np.asarray(img)
                self.imgTrainSmpl[index] = np.subtract(imgArr,self.meanImg).tolist()
                index += 1

            #for img in self.imgTrainSmpl:
                #print img
        except:
            print Exception 


    #2. get the covaraince matrix for each digit
    def getCov(self):
        self.imgCov=[]
        dgtArr = np.asarray(self.imgTrainSmpl).T
        dgtCov = np.cov(dgtArr)
        self.imgCov.append(dgtCov)
        #for img in self.imgCov:
            #print img

    #3. get the eigen vectors from the covariance matrix
    def getEigen(self):
        self.eigVec=[]
        self.eigVal=[]
        dgtArr = np.asarray(self.imgCov)
        tmpEigVal,tmpEigVec=np.linalg.eig(dgtArr)
        self.eigVal.append(tmpEigVal.tolist())
        self.eigVec.append(tmpEigVec.tolist())

        #print "\nEigen values:\n"
        #for img in self.eigVal:
            #print img

        #print "\nEigen vectors:\n"
        #for img in self.eigVec:
            #print img


    def sortEV(self):
        self.eigValArr = np.asarray(self.eigVal[0][0])
        self.eigVecArr = np.asarray(self.eigVec[0][0])
        self.srtdInd = np.argsort(np.abs(self.eigValArr))
        self.srtdEigValArr = self.eigValArr[self.srtdInd]
        self.srtdEigVecArr = self.eigVecArr[self.srtdInd]
        self.srtdEigVec = self.srtdEigVecArr.real.tolist()
        #print self.srtdEigValArr[0]
        print len(self.srtdInd.tolist())
        #print self.eigVec[self.srtdInd[0]]
        #print np.asarray(self.srtdEigVec).shape
        #for img in self.srtdEigVecArr:
            #print img
        #self.drawEig()

    def plotVal(self):
        """
        plt.figure()
        plt.scatter(np.asarray(self.eigVal).real)
        plt.show()
        """

    def drawEig(self):
        for vec in self.srtdEigVec[:10]:
            self.drawEigV(vec)


    def drawEigV(self,digit):
        plt.figure()
        fig=plt.imshow(np.asarray(digit).reshape(28,28),origin='upper')
        fig.set_cmap('gray_r')
        fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        plt.savefig(str(random.randint(0,10000))+".png")
        #plt.show()
        plt.close()



    def drawChar(self,digit):
        plt.figure()
        fig=plt.imshow(np.asarray(digit).reshape(28,28),clim=(-1,1.0),origin='upper')
        fig.set_cmap('gray_r')
        fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        plt.show()
        plt.close()


    def drawSmpl(self):
        for img in self.imgTrainSmpl:
            self.drawChar(img) 


    def singleStep(self):
        self.val, self.vec = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(np.array(self.imgTrainSmpl).transpose()))
        self.srtd = np.argsort(self.val)[::-1]
        print self.val


#asnmnt4=PCAMNIST()
#asnmnt4.singleStep()
asnmnt4=PCAMNIST()
asnmnt4.subMean()
asnmnt4.getCov()
asnmnt4.getEigen()
asnmnt4.sortEV()
asnmnt4.drawEig()
#asnmnt4.plotVal()
"""
asnmnt4.getSorted()
asnmnt4.printTopEigenVal()
"""
```

Although the above code runs perfectly and all the array sizes match the given dataset, it generates the following images a eigen vectors:
[image: Eigen vectors as images]

Clearly the eigen vectors make no sense as they have to represent the features of the dataset which in this case should be digits. Any help is appreciated. If you are trying to run this code you might have to install the MNIST package and download data from link.

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing this by-hand rather than using a tool like scikit-learn? Here's an example of PCA on a different digits dataset: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html

Comment: Just for learning it the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're plotting the **rows** of the eigenvector matrix. The eigenvectors are in the **columns** of the matrix, as you can see in the [`np.linalg.eig` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

You should change

```
self.eigVec.append(tmpEigVec.tolist())
```

to

```
self.eigVec.append(np.transpose(tmpEigVec).tolist())
```

and I believe it will work as expected.

Comment: The same was pointed out by another user; he removed his solution since it is appending to the list in a weird manner making the shape as (1,784,784,1) which results as array value error. But thanks for pointing it, any alternate solution is appreciated.

Comment: OK – there may be a better solution, but I believe the root of the problem is what I mentioned here: the eigenvectors are in the columns not the rows.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by several users the problem was with the eigenvectors to make it work instead of changing the append logic, simply modify the draw function as:

```
def drawEig(self):
        for vec in self.srtdEigVecArr.T[:10]:
            self.drawEigV(vec)
```

Now, the eigenvectors make sense:
[image]